# Docker build freezes on command

Tags: docker

[Multiple Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BDocker%5D%20freezes) have been asked, but neither the solutions nor the suggestions work for me. I am using the [manjarolinux docker](https://github.com/manjaro/manjaro-docker). The image installs most of the stuff in the dockerfile:

```
FROM manjarolinux/base

RUN pacman-mirrors -g
RUN pacman -Syy
RUN rm -fr /etc/pacman.d/gnupg 
RUN pacman-key --init 
RUN pacman-key --populate archlinux
RUN pacman-key --populate manjaro
# RUN pacman-key --refresh-keys
RUN pacman -Syyu --noconfirm
RUN pacman -S --noconfirm gnupg
RUN pacman -Fyy --noconfirm

RUN pacman -Sy --noconfirm vim git gzip yay # this line 
RUN pacman -Sy --noconfirm sudo fakeroot make

RUN pacman -Sy --noconfirm gcc clang 

RUN groupadd sudo wheel
RUN useradd -m -d /home/manjarouser -s /bin/zsh -g sudo wheel manjarouser

USER manjarouser
```

However, after the line marked with `this line`, the build simply freezes:

[image: build freeze step]

Comment: Just don't use buildkit. This only happens when using buildkit, see https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1267

Comment: @Braiam, I am not using buildkit.

Comment: Run build with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0`, you will see that it doesn't happen.

Comment: @Braiam. if you meant `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -t cpp-docker .`, then it somehow is not working. Perhaps, I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Ran fine for me, even with buildkit, right up to to the `groupadd` step. Guessing something wrong with the host environment. (disk space? corrupt base image? network?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@d4rk4ng31, my Archlinux custom docker container was doing the same thing in my build process. I was not able to pinpoint the exact reason, but it comes from a post-transaction hook in `systemd` (/usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles --create). If you were to launch a basic container with `docker run -it --rm manjarolinux/base bash` and run that command, it would hang your container.

In my case, it was because I was using `archlinux/base`, which is now deprecated. Simply changing to the following fixed my issue:

```
FROM archlinux
```

I would verify if there is a similar deprecation issue going on with Manjaro.

Comment: So, I should switch to `FROM manjarolinux`?